# BeautifulSoup: how to get all article links from this link?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, web-crawler

I want to get all article link from "https://www.cnnindonesia.com/search?query=covid"
Here is my code:

```
links = []
base_url = requests.get(f"https://www.cnnindonesia.com/search?query=covid")
soup = bs(base_url.text, 'html.parser')
cont = soup.find_all('div', class_='container')

for l in cont:
    l_cont = l.find_all('div', class_='l_content')
    for bf in l_cont:
        bf_cont = bf.find_all('div', class_='box feed')
        for lm in bf_cont:
            lm_cont = lm.find('div', class_='list media_rows middle')
            for article in lm_cont.find_all('article'):
                a_cont = article.find('a', href=True)
                if url:
                    link = a['href']
                    links.append(link)
```

and result is as follows:

```
links
[]
```

Comment: There are no links in `soup.find_all('div', class_='l_content')`. Take a look again at the soup obj/webpage and find what exactly you're looking for and go from there. What link are you trying to extract?

Comment: i want extract link of class_= "list media_rows middle" sir

Comment: Look at the raw HTML. Element with *<div class="list media_rows middle">* has article sub-elements but there are no a-href inside. Those links are populated dynamically using JavaScript. You would need to use something like Selenium to parse after the browser renders the page. See updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each article has this structure:

```
<article class="col_4">
   <a href="https://www.cnnindonesia.com/...">
       <span>...</span>
       <h2 class="title">...</h2>
   </a>
</article>
```

Simpler to iterate over the *article* elements then look for the a-href element.

Try:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

links = []
response = requests.get(f"https://www.cnnindonesia.com/search?query=covid")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    url = article.find('a', href=True)
    if url:
        link = url['href']
        print(link)
        links.append(link)
print(links)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.cnnindonesia.com/nasional/...pola-sawah-di-laut-natuna-utara
...
['https://www.cnnindonesia.com/nasional/...pola-sawah-di-laut-natuna-utara', ...
'https://www.cnnindonesia.com/gaya-hidup/...ikut-penerbangan-gravitasi-nol']
```

**Update:**

If want to extract the URLs that are dynamically added by JavaScript inside the `<div class="list media_rows middle">` element then you must use something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) that can extract the content after the full page is rendered in the web browser.

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.cnnindonesia.com/search?query=covid'
links = []

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
pathToChromeDriver = "chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=pathToChromeDriver,
                           options=options)
try:
    browser.get(url)
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    html = browser.page_source
    content = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'media_rows')
    for elt in content.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'article'):
        link = elt.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
        href = link.get_attribute('href')
        if href:
            print(href)
            links.append(href)
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

Comment: that's good answer sirr, but i want to take articles link inside class_='list media_rows middle" but i still got null result on my list here is my summary code for that class:

m_cont = lm.find('div', class_='list media_rows middle')
            for article in lm_cont.find_all('article'):
                a_cont = article.find('a', href=True)
                if url:
                    link = a['href']
                    links.append(link)

Comment: okayy thankyou btw how to access next button and scraping it with selenium in my case? sry for my bad english..

Comment: You can find the button element by TEXT or XPATH' e.g. //a[@class="btn_more"] then call click() function on that element; see [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-click-on-a-link-in-selenium-with-python).

Comment: i still don't get it bro:( can u help me please..

Comment: Post a new question showing where you are in your code using Selenium and what is not working. You can find the next button with `btn = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn__more')`.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, can't add comments not enough reputation.

I think this line:
`for url in lm_row_cont.find_all('a'):`

Should have the a tag as `'<a>'`

Or you could use regex (skipping the above) to match the relevant items after grabbing a div.